# Create prototypes for subobjects, javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this object:

```
var order = {
  customer: 'Joe',
  items: [
    {
      id: 123,
      title: 'VCR',
    }
  ]
};
```

I want to create logic for both the order and the items object. So I need to write a class that instantiate another class.

The Order class:

```
function Order(customer, items){
  this.customer = customer;
  this.items = items;
}

Order.prototype = {
  getCustomer: function(){
    console.log(this.customer);
  }
};
```

The Item class:

```
function Item(id, title){
  this.id = id;
  this.title = title;
}

Item.prototype = {
  getItemId: function(){
    console.log(this.id);
  }
};
```

The instance:

```
var myOrder = new Order(order.customer, order.items);
```

Now this is what I want to do:

```
myOrder.items[0].getItemId() //123
myOrder.items[0].getCustomer() //Joe
```

How do I make this work? I need to connect the classes somehow and add a prototype to the item objects.

Jsbin: https://jsbin.com/nofofifuka/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Add an "order" property to the item, and pass in the order object when you construct the item.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have an `Order` class with a single element that is the `order` object? Why not make your `Order` objects have a `customer` and `items` field instead? That is, make `Order` a model that represents the same data as your object, instead of a wrapper.

Comment: @apsillers Yes you're right. Fixed it.

Comment: @PerStröm You may also wish to do the same for `Item`'s `id` and `title`. Also, your `getCustomer` getter doesn't reflect your changed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to call the `Item` constructor on the elements in `items`.

```
function Order(order){
    this.customer = customer;
    this.items = order.items.map(function (item) {
         return new Item(item);
    });
}
```

`Array.prototype.map` calls the given function once for each element in the source array, and returns a new array, of the same length, containing the results of the calling the function.

Alternatively you could make your `Item` constructor have a few extra smarts so it can instantiate itself if called without `new`:

```
function Item(item){
    if (! (this instanceof Item)) { return new Item(item); }
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
}
```

Then you can use it directly in the `map`:

```
function Order(order){
    this.order = order;
    order.items = order.items.map(Item);
}
```

Comment: Note that this will mutate the object passed in, if the OP cares about that. (Actually, the OP just changed the code structure that avoids this problem but also renders the current phrasing of your answer's code different from the question.)

Comment: With this solution you get a identical prototype for each item. This takes unnecassary memory. Do you have way were you can put a single prototype "one level up" that handles items logic?

Comment: That's actually kinda how prototypes work already :) Things in the prototype are not copied when the class is instantiated. So there will only be one `getItemId` in memory. See https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve has nothing to do with inheritance, I think. Can you check if code below satisfies what you want to achieve?

```
function Order(id){
  this.id = id;
  this.items = [];
}

Order.prototype.addItem = function(item) {
  this.items.push(item);
};

Order.prototype.getItems = function() {
  return this.items;
};

Order.prototype.getItem = function(id) {
  for (var i = 0, l = this.items.length; i<l; i++) {
    if (this.items[i].id === id) return this.items[i];
  }

  return;
};

function Item(id, customer) {
  this.id = id;
  this.customer = customer;
}

var order1 = new Order(1);
order1.addItem(new Item(123, 'customer1'));
order1.addItem(new Item(345, 'customer2'));
order1.addItem(new Item(456, 'customer3'));

console.log(order1.getItems());
console.log(order1.getItem(345));
```

Comment: I believe customer info should belong to order class, but depends on the project of course.

Answer (score 0):

On my glance, such case should reflect the following situation in real life:
Certain buyer(`customer`) makes an `order` which may contains many product positions (`items`). 
That items have their unique characteristics and should added separately into the order.
The Order class:

```
 function Order(customer){
      this.customer = customer;
      this.items = [];
    }

    Order.prototype = {
      constructor: Order,
      addItem: function(id, title){
         this.items.push(new Item(id, title)); 
      },
      getCustomer: function(){
        console.log(this.customer);
      }
    };
```

The Item class:

```
function Item(id, title){
  this.id = id;
  this.title = title;
}

Item.prototype = {
  constructor: Item,
  getItemId: function(){
    console.log(this.id);
  }
};
```

The instance:

```
var myOrder = new Order(order.customer);
order.items.map(function (item) {
    myOrder.addItem(item.id, ite.title);
});

myOrder.items[0].getItemId() //123
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.map` is the right tool, but in order to deliver the logic you ask for, I think it should be used more like this:

```
function Order(o){
    this.items = o.items.map(function(obj){
        obj.customer = o.customer;
        var r = obj;
        r.getItemId = function(){ console.log(obj.id); };
        r.getItemTitle = function(){ console.log(obj.title); };
        r.getCustomer = function(){ console.log(obj.customer); };
        return r;
    });
}

var myOrder = new Order(order);

myOrder.items[0].getCustomer();
myOrder.items[0].getItemId();
myOrder.items[0].getItemTitle();
```

Considering it is obvious from the code, I didn't add above, but thanks to line 4 (`var r = obj;`) you can use customer, id, and title properties of `myOrder.items[n]` as well as all getters.